# Photon rate definition in input-output formalism: why such definition commonly used?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, waves, quantum-optics, research-level, cavity-qed

I consider a one dimensional waveguide. I study free field propagation on it. I apply periodic boundary condition with periodization length $L$ to describe the physics with Fourier series and not fourier transform.

Within this volume $L$, the total Hamiltonian of the system is:

$$H=\sum_{l} \hbar \omega_k a^{\dagger}_k a_k$$

I want to know what is the number of photons per unit time which cross a section $x$ of my waveguide at a time $t$. The photons travels at velocity $c$. What is done on page 68 of [Introduction to Quantum Noise, Measurement and Amplification](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4729), is to say (without explanations), that this number is basically:

$$\dot{N}(x)=\langle b^{\dagger}_{\rightarrow}(x,t) b_{\rightarrow}(x,t)\rangle $$
With: $b_{\rightarrow}(x,t) \equiv \sqrt{\frac{c}{L}} \sum_{l>0}  a_k e^{i(kx-\omega_k t)}$

My main question here is: **Why this result ? Why would this represent the average number of photon which cross a section $x$ of my waveguide per unit time ?**

Indeed, I would define things differently. Basically to have access to a photon rate, I must know the total number of photon in my system, their velocity, and their distribution along my waveguide. This is represented by the following operator.

$$N_{\rightarrow} = \sum_l a^{\dagger}_l a_l$$

Dividing by my waveguide length $L$, I have access to the number of right moving photons per unit length (I need to assume something about how photons are distributed, else I cannot do anything). Then, the number of photons that will cross a section $x$ of my waveguide during a time $dt$ will correspond to the number of photons contained in a length $cdt$. If I divide by $dt$ I have access to the number of photons that will cross the section $x$ of my waveguide per unit time: the photon rate. It gives:

$$\dot{N}(x)=\frac{c}{L}\sum_{l>0} \langle a^{\dagger}_l a_l\rangle \neq \langle b^{\dagger}_{\rightarrow}(x,t) b_{\rightarrow}(x,t)\rangle $$

Why is my way of defining things incorrect ? Why is the first way of defining things used ? I don't understand.

[edit] I remember this other question I asked some time ago, with the associated answer by @Wolpertinger [Quantum input-output theory : Why do we multiply by density of mode to have a number of photon **per unit of time**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484716/quantum-input-output-theory-why-do-we-multiply-by-density-of-mode-to-have-a-nu?rq=1)

I have to think about it more but I think it motivates well the first definition of photon rate. In the end I can also ask the question: does the photon rate definition is partially subjective ? Photon is a concept in itself, we have to define at some point what we call a photon rate. We then have two possible definitions that each have advantages and drewback. Which is why the two definition given here do not always match. The community prefered for some reasons the first definition. Would that make sense ?

Comment: It looks to me like the definitions you've given in fact agree and the does not equals in your last equation should actually be an equals.. what the issue?

Comment: @jgerber it would save my life if that was the case ! Maybe I missed something but I will have crossed term in the first definition, not in the second: terms like $a_l^{\dagger}a_p$ with $p \neq l$. Do you agree ?

Comment: Yes, you will have the cross terms, but those will not contribute when you take the expectation value.

Comment: @jgerber for a fixed photon number they won't, but for a coherent state (for instance, or any other state) they will. The photon number operator should work for an arbitrary state.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I would need to think longer about it than I have time for right now to give a satisfying answer.

Comment: @jgerber Actually I remember this old question I asked https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484716/quantum-input-output-theory-why-do-we-multiply-by-density-of-mode-to-have-a-nu?rq=1 I think it is an element of answer for this here (I have to think more carefully about this). But in the very end I guess the answer would be that the definition of photon rate is partially subjective of how you want to define it. I guess either mine or the other definition could hold (each has advantages and drewbacks somehow). But it is just a feeling right now.

Comment: Yes exactly. You have to keep track of which operators represent amplitudes of standing photon waves and which represent amplitudes of travelling photon waves. The operators have different dimensions in each case. Operators representing amplitudes of standing waves are dimensionless and their magnitudes ($a^{\dagger}a$) are proportional to energies while operators representing amplitudes of travelling waves have dimensions of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}$ and their magnitudes are proportional to powers (or energy flows).

Comment: I'm used to working in a cavity which is a fixed finite size volume. In this case the quantized modes do not travel. There are only standing waves. This is different from the waveguide you describe with periodic boundary conditions which can in fact have travelling waves.. This difference is why I would need to think about it.

Comment: @jgerber yes but in the discussion we shouldn't be confused by the continuum limit. This changes the definition of operators, I agree but the ending point of the discussion shouldn't depend on this. In both (continuum or discrete), I could end up with two definitions. I am wondering if actually both could be taken as photon rate, it is kinda subjective to decide which one to take.